# why thinks with an s with it is important that

Tags: subjunctives

9. It is important to remember that Janine (think) 
   very differently from you. She may not agree to the changes you have made in 
   the organization of the company.

the answer is thinks why not think isn't it a case of  mandative subjunctive so the s should be taken off

https://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/subjunctiveexercise.htm

Comment: No, not at all. It's nothing more than just a simple statement of fact. Compare your sentence with this sentence: **It is important to know that the earth is round.**

Answer (score 1):

"It is important that" is a value statement, which can be *immediately* followed by a subjunctive clause to avoid making an assertion about the truth of that clause:

> It is important that **he remember**. (But I don't know whether he will.)

On the other hand, "Remember that" introduces the next clause as true, requiring normal conjugation:

> He remembers that **Janine thinks** differently. (And I know she does.)

Putting it together yields:

> It is important that **he remember** that **Janine thinks** differently. (I know that Janine thinks differently, but I don't know whether he will remember.)

<sub>(Note: I used "important that" to show the difference between the two types of clauses. In the original sentence we have "important to" but the second clause is still the same, with "Janine thinks.")</sub>